# Saving image bytes into hidden field HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using following code to upload the image

```
$selectFile = $('<input type="file">').click();
      $selectFile.change(function (e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event){
              var img = new Image();
              img.onload = function(){
                  $div.append('<figure class="images"><img src="'+ event.target.result +'" draggable="true" alt=""></figure>');
              }
              img.src = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

      });
```

When I look at the `event.target.result` it contains something like `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB`

I am not sure if these are the image bytes? I am not very much familiar with HTML 5.
How do I get the image bytes so that i can store them into some hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data after the "data:image/jpeg;base64," is a Base64 encoded version of the image.  You can convert it to a byte array using:

```
var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
```

But I'm not sure why you'd want to, when the Base64 is fine for rendering an image anyway with :

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...." >
```

Comment: I am not concerned about rendering, it is working fine. But i need to save the image into database. So i need bytes for that?

Comment: You could just save the Base64 string into the database, then just render it back later on using the method I described.  Otherwise if you need it as a byte array, you could use atob(b64Data);

Comment: Yes that worked fine. I would need still need to convert base64 string into bytes so that we can do some image manipulation (resize etc). The base64 string seem to have some invalid characters as its throwing error while using atob.

Comment: Are you using just the bit after "data:image/jpeg;base64," ?  That bit is not part of the Base64 string.  What's your error?

Comment: Had to skip "data:image/jpeg;base64," from decoding. It works fine now. Thanks